# Переопределение методов класса String

Tags: c#, строки

```
static class MyString : String
{
    static public string[] Split(this string s)
    {
        return Split(s, @"\t");
    }

    static public string[] Split(this string s, string d)
    {
        return Regex.Split(s, d);
    }
}
```

У переменной типа string есть методы. Как я понял эти методы принадлежат классу String. В идеале мне нужно переопределить метод Split не в моем классе, а в классе String, но у меня это не получилось (мало опыта).

Два вопроса:

1. Возможно ли переопределение в классе String, чтобы...

   string a;
   a.Split();

...у переменной a метод Split вызывался мой?

2. Как возможно реализовать мой вариант с моим методом? Выдает ошибку:

> CS0713    Статический класс "MyString" не может быть производным
>   от типа "string". Статические классы должны быть производными от
>   object.

Comment: Класс string является `sealed` т.е. microsoft запретила его модифицировать. Аналогичная ситуация в других языках. это нужно для порядка, что бы все string работали одинаково. Обратите внимание, функция split для regex находится в классе самого regex, а не string.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать методы расширения и не написать методо вроде `MySplit` ?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сделать класс с расширениями, в таком случае вам не надо наследоваться, достаточно того, что вы написали this string в аргументах

Comment: Вы можете пользовательскую функцию вложить в отдельный свой класс, но модифицировать split самого string нельзя.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1.Возможно ли переопределение в классе String, чтобы...

Нет. [Метод-расширение](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) не может переопределить метод, объявленный в классе.

Если в классе уже есть метод с такой же сигнатурой, то он всегда будет иметь приоритет над методом-расширением.

В Вашем случае сигнатура первого метода совпадает с уже существующим методом [`String.Split(params char[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx). Соответственно, при вызове:

```
var result = a.Split();
```

вызовется стандартный метод с пустым массивом разделителей. Согласно документации строка в данном случае делится по любым пробельным символам, а не только по табуляции:

> ...  If the separator argument is null or contains no characters, the method treats white-space characters as the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard; they return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

Вы все еще сможете вызвать свой метод, обратившись к нему напрямую:

```
MyString.Split(a);
```

Но, чтобы использовать его как расширение Вам придется дать ему другое имя. Советую дать осмысленное название, связанное с тем, что делает метод, например `SplitByTab`.

Второй метод по сигнатуре не совпадает с существующими, но для удобочитаемости кода лучше дать ему более говорящее название, отличное от стандартного `Split`.

> Как возможно реализовать мой вариант с моим методом? Выдает ошибку:

Для того-чтобы объявить методы-расширения не нужно наследоваться от класса. Уберите наследование от `String`:

```
static class MyStringExtensions
{
    static public string[] SplitByTab(this string s)
    {
        return SplitByRegex(s, @"\t");
    }

    static public string[] SplitByRegex(this string s, string pattern)
    {
        return Regex.Split(s, pattern);
    }
}
```

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Но, когда оставляю у своих методов те же имена, у a.Split() появляются 2 новые перегрузки. Значит ли это, что имена менять не обязательно и все будет корректно работать?

Comment: @KirillK. Второй метод получится использовать не переименовывая, хоть это и сбивает с толку. Первый нет, т.к. его сигнатура совпадает с объявленным. Сейчас попробую расписать.

Comment: @defaultlocale, все получится, потому что char[] и string - это разные классы

Comment: @Grundy речь идет о методе без аргументов, который рассматривается как метод с пустым массивом.

Comment: @KirillK. Обновил ответ, описал более подробно, что произойдет с методами.

Comment: @defaultlocale, а, значит я не правильно понял :)

Comment: @defaultlocale, ответ исчерпывающий. Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы не можете наследоваться от класса `System.String`, так как он является `sealed`
2. Вы можете добавить свои методы для `string` с помощью extension-a:

   ```
   public static class MyStringExtensions
   {
       public static string[] MySplit(this string s)
       {
           return s.Split('\t');
       }

       public static string[] MySplit(this string s, string d)
       {
           return Regex.Split(s, d);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Вы не можете переопределить уже имеющиеся методы в `string`. Даже с помощью extension-а, так как в этом случае вызываться будет метод из самого класса, а не из extension-a

Answer (score 2):

Используйте методы расширения и определяйте свой собственный метод. Вот пример с консольным приложением:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ST = "teststring";
        ST.MySplit();
    } 
}
static class ext
{
    public static string MySplit(this string str)
    {
        return str + "!!!";
    }
}
```

}